# Nuget Pack Default Option Values

Tags: nuget, default-value, pack

I'm trying to make it so that when I run nuget pack it always outputs to the same directory, rather than typing it in every time. The following link suggests that defaults are possible by setting config file key/value pairs.

http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-file

However, there doesn't seem to be a clear syntax. I've tried using keys such as:

- OutputDirectory
- DefaultOutputDirectory
- DefaultPackOutputDirectory

None of which worked. Maybe the "DefaultPushSource" is a hard-coded key in the executable? Is it even possible to set default values for pack options using the config file approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the list of settings that can be defined in the nuget.config: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings

There is no nuget.config settings for nuget.exe pack command yet.

Answer (score 0):

@Chad H : There is no way to do this right now. The best way I can recommend is to create an alias for the nuget pack command which has the outputDirectory flag set to whatever path you want your output at :

https://docs.nuget.org/consume/command-line-reference#pack-command